# Components I've added to JPanel does not appears when I'm running an app

Tags: java, swing, scala

I try to create Grid table with buttons

```
package midterm



import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.GridLayout
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import scala.swing.Button
import scala.swing.MainFrame
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication



object Main extends SimpleSwingApplication {
def top = new MainFrame {
title = "Hello, World!"
val panel = new JPanel()
var btn = Array.ofDim[JButton](8,8)
//contents =new JButton()
 for(i<-0 to 7){
    for(j<-0 to 7){
      btn(i)(j)= new JButton("vsdf")
      btn(i)(j).setBounds(i*80,j*80,80,80)
      btn(i)(j).setBackground(Color.BLUE)
      panel.add(btn(i)(j))
    }
 }
}
}
```

compiling is good but in output only frame without buttons,that's all. please show me my error!!

Answer (score 4):

You've added buttons to the JPanel, but haven't placed panel on the frame (so the frame ends up with an empty contents).
Instead you had to write something like:

```
object Main extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
  //...
    contents = new JPanel()
  //...
  contents+= btn(i)(j)
  }
}
```

[Please, see Scala Swing tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/imaier/Mon,%202009-11-02,%2008:55/scala-swing-design.pdf).